# Overlapping MQ Cluster and reply message delivery with IBM MQ

Tags: ibm-mq

I have two clusters `CLUSMES` and `CLUSHUBS`.  Each cluster has two queue managers.

Cluster `CLUSMES` has QMGRS: `QMGR1A` and `QMGR1B`
Cluster `CLUSHUBS` has QMGRS: `QMGR3A` and `QMGR3B`

There is a Gateway QMGR: `QMGR2`, which forms the overlap and is a partial repository in each MQ cluster.

Request messages are sent out from either `QMGR1A/B` to either `QMGR3A/B` via `QMGR2` which acts as a cluster Load balance to `QMGR3A/B` (This works fine) and a reply is expected back to the sending QMGR.

All channel connectivity is in place and fully functional. The problem is how to return the message from where it came from. The replying QMGR connects to QMGR3A/B and issues a put. I will either get a REMOTE_QMGR not found (`MQRC 2087`) or a MQ Object not found (`MQRC 2085`) depending on how I have it configured. The message header of the message contains the `ReplytoQueue` and `ReplyToQMgr` properly. I would like to have the replying application just issue a put and have it delivered to the proper queue in `CLUSMES`, but this is proving to be extremely difficult. I have played with Remote QMGR Alias and QAlias on the GateWay Qmgr: `QMGR2`, but no luck. There is got to be a simple trick to this and there are plenty of examples, but I have not been able to implement one successfully. A clear cut example of what my return path should be would be most helpful. Keep in mind, that the `ReplyToQMgr`is in the `MQMD` and resolution needs to occur from that. I need resolution to occur at the `QMGR2` level, where both clusters are known. Concrete full suggestions appreciated.

MQ Definitions on the QMGR1A/B, where the REPLY is expected:

```
DEFINE QLOCAL('SERVER.REPLYQ') CLUSTER('CLUSMES')
```

On QMGR2 ( The Gateway for message hoping)

```
DEFINE NAMELIST(CLUSTEST) NAMES(CLUSMES,CLUSHUBS)

DEFINE QALIAS(SERVER.ALIAS.REPLYQ) TARGQ(SERVER.REPLYQ) CLUSTER(CLUSTEST) DEFBIND(NOTFIXED)

DEFINE QREMOTE(QMGR1A) RNAME(' ') RQMNAME(QMGR1A) XMITQ('') CLUSTER(CLUSHUBS)
DEFINE QREMOTE(QMGR1B) RNAME(' ') RQMNAME(QMGR1B) XMITQ('') CLUSTER(CLUSHUBS)
```

On MQMGR3A/B QALIAS(SERVER.ALIAS.REPLYQ) cluster queue. The Gateway QMGR could not resolve the baseQ:  mqrc_unknown_alias_base_q 2082

This was the configuration when trying to resolve it using the cluster.

Comment: Few things are wrong above. 1. the way to reference a `NAMELIST` is the `CLUSNL` attribute not the `CLUSTER` attribute. 2. I'm do not believe that you can have a clustered `QALIAS` on one server that is meant to resolve to a clustered `QLOCAL` on a another server if you plan to put to that `QALIAS` from yet another clustered queue manager but I would have to test this. Can you specify what values the requesting app puts into `ReplyToQueue` and `ReplyToQmgr` and if the replying app is using those same values, if note what queue name and queue manager name is the replying app specifying?

Comment: If the requesting app is specifying `SERVER.REPLYQ` in `ReplyToQueue` and `QMGR1A` in the `ReplyToQmgr`, the you would not need the `QALIAS(SERVER.ALIAS.REPLYQ)` object on `QMGR2`, only the `QREMOTE(QMGR1A)` object.  (replace `1A` with `2A` above for second requesting qmgr).

Comment: If the replying app is not using the values specified in `ReplyToQueue` and `ReplyToQmgr` and is instead hard coding a single value such as `SERVER.ALIAS.REPLYQ` as the queue it sends replies to then you would have no way to use MQ functionality to route them back to the correct Request queue manager.

Answer (score 1):

When the request message is sent by the application it would specify `ReplyToQMgr` of either `QMGR1A` and `QMGR1B` and `ReplytoQueue` with the name of the queue that is present on `QMGR1A` and `QMGR1B`, the reply queue need not be clustered.

On gateway queue manager `QMGR2` you would define the following objects:

```
DEFINE QREMOTE(QMGR1A) RNAME('') RQMNAME(QMGR1A) XMITQ('') CLUSTER(CLUSHUBS)
DEFINE QREMOTE(QMGR1B) RNAME('') RQMNAME(QMGR1B) XMITQ('') CLUSTER(CLUSHUBS)
```

This would allows any queue manager in the cluster `CLUSHUBS` to route reply messages back to `QMGR1A` and `QMGR1B` via gateway queue manager `QMGR2`.

---

If you want to limit queues on `QMGR1A` and `QMGR1B` that queue managers in the `CLUSHUBS` cluster can put to you would need to take a different approach.  Let me know if that is what you need and I will update my answer with some suggestions.

Comment: For this to work, does the replying application need to specify the ReplyToQMGR in the MQOD message header? This would mean an application change which should be avoided if possible. Is there an alternative method?

Comment: If you mean the requesting app, leave it blank, the qmgr your app is connected to will be filled in.

Comment: The server/application that puts the reply message is putting it to the default QMGR it is connected to. Your suggested solution implies, that the application needs to issue the PUT to the REPLYToQmgr which would have a QALIAS define on QMGR2. The actual case is, when the application issues a put to the connected QMGR, how to route that message across Clusters. I have a QREMOTE QMGR Alias defined to QMGR2 clustered to CLUSMES, but it only delivers round robin style and ignores the real destination. Changing the application is not an option at this time.

Comment: @SteveO the replying application can connect to the default QMGR (`QMGR3A` or `QMGR3B` in your example).  When it puts the message it sets the base queue manager name to what was in the ReplyToQMgr (`QMGR1A` or `QMGR1B`) in this case and the queue to what was in the ReplyToQueue.  The default queue manager will handle sending it via the `CLUSHUBS` cluster to QMGR2 which would then route it to the correct destination queue manager.

Comment: @SteveO Note the two objects I mentioned defining on `QMGR2` are QREMOTE QMGR Alias where the RQMNAME is filled in.  Because RQMNAME is filled in it will not round robin the messages.  If you left RQMNAME blank the messages would round robin only if the Reply queue is clustered and as I mentioned it does not need to be clustered.

Comment: @SteveO it would help me to help you if you could edit your question and provide the actual objects defined end to end on QMGR1A/B, QMGR2, and QMGR3A/B.  Change the names and mask out any information you do not want to share.

Comment: @SteveO did you you get a working solution?  Did my answer help?

Comment: Yes a working solution is in place, but not based on the discussion here. After many variations on the proposed solution and not being able to resolve, I worked with sending application developer to use system identifiers in the queue name. The recipient/reply application which ran many instances of the app originally, was able to change their config to match the name. The queues were then able to map to a specific destination rather then rely on clustering and or aliasing conventions.

Comment: @SteveO, glad that you got it worked out.  You could write up a example as a answer to your own question with more details for the benefit of people who run across the question in the future.